# How to find the sum of all the first columns of matrices in a list using lapply function in R?

Tags: r, list, matrix, apply, lapply

Suppose I have a list having 3 matrices. I am not able to figure out how to find the sum of 1st columns of each matrix and get the result.

```
Eg:
A=matrix(c(1:4),nrow=2,ncol=2)
B=matrix(c(5:8),nrow=2,ncol=2)
C=matrix(c(9:12),nrow=2,ncol=2)

MyList=list(A,B,C)

The list is:
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    7
[2,]    6    8

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    9   11
[2,]   10   12
```

I want to find the sum of 1st column elements from each of the matrices using lapply.
    **Expected result:** 3,11,19 *(in a list format of course)*

Comment: Try `lapply(MyList, function(x) sum(x[,1]))`

Comment: @akrun, thank you this worked. but could you please explain the code. What is the second parameter for? Sorry, but I am not really good in R and am trying to understand how the "apply" family works.

Comment: Loop through the list with `lapply`, using the anonymous function, extract the first column `x[,1]` and get the `sum` of it

Comment: Sorry, one more question. Now how will I be able to use my "own created function (a user defined function)" and then use it in lapply? Suppose, now I want to find the product of the first columns in each matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Using `purrr` package you may run the following code:

Your data:

```
A=matrix(c(1:4),nrow=2,ncol=2)
B=matrix(c(5:8),nrow=2,ncol=2)
C=matrix(c(9:12),nrow=2,ncol=2)
```

Create a list:

```
mylist <- list(A,B,C)
```

Then run `map` using `colSums` function which produces sums by columns. Using again `map` you may extract the first element, i.e. sum by first column:

```
library(purrr)
mylist %>% 
    map(colSums) %>% 
    map(1)
```

This is the output:

```
[[1]]
[1] 3

[[2]]
[1] 11

[[3]]
[1] 19
```